# Fetching specific data from mongodb collections using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

He yall, I need some help with my node and MongoDB application.

So I have a MongoDB database and im fetching the data using node.js with express.js. I fetch the data fine with my application, and I can even send it to my browser. But I want to render a template I have (shown below).

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Hello my name is {{ name }}, and my email is {{ email }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var usersSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String
});

mongoose.model('emaildata', usersSchema);
```

But when i try and do this with this script

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// MongoDb Server
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/emailApp');

// Load all files in models folder. Importing models and schemas
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/models').forEach(function(filename) {
  if (~filename.indexOf('.js')) require(__dirname + '/models/' + filename)
});

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('emaildata').find(function(err, emaildata) {
    res.send(emaildata)
    // res.render('email', { title: 'Emails', email: emaildata.email, name: emaildata.name });
  });
});




// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

It doesn't render anything. I believe the problem is 1. im not using the right syntax to identify the specific data in the object, like name or email. I try and do this about half way down my script by the app.get('/data'....
2. I'm not importing the object correctly, so when I try and use the data to render my template, there is nothing.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I never use mongoose before, but I guess that problem come from the way you retrieve emaildata. Since you are not using findOne, your emaildata result should be an array right?

Answer (score 0):

First, `res.send` will not use your template file.

I assume that your template file's name is "email", so use `res.render('email', {information : emaildata})`
and in your template file, use {{ information.name}} and {{ information.email }} to render them.(I haven't used hjs, so there may be some syntax error.)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the comment. So it kinda works, What im getting is when i send this                                                                               res.render('email', { title: 'Emails', information: emaildata}); to this template                                                                                                  <p>Hello my name is {{ information }}, and im {{ information }} years old!</p> it send me my whole json object from my database. So the fetching and sending works great. The only problem is that i can specify name or email from inside of my json object.

Comment: Adding onto the previous comment, ran out of characters. When i try and do information.email or information.name in my template nothing send to my web page. Not sure why. Help!

Comment: @YisroelArnson `hjs` is **not** being maintained and may not support express 4.x, i recommend you to use [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) and try again.

Comment: But when i put {{ information }} instead of {{ information.name }} it works. It send my whole object... But i cant figure out the syntax to specifically get the name.

Comment: @YisroelArnson I just mentioned hjs is **not** being maintained.And i can't find its document.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

Import the Modal schema

```
var mydataSchema = require('.<directory>/<yourmodalname>');
```

Then if you already have some data in your database, get that also fetched by updating this into your modal

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var usersSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String
}, {collection : '<tableName>' });

mongoose.model('emaildata', usersSchema);
```

Then get all the data:

First declare the router

```
var router = express.Router();
```

get the data

```
router.route('/userData')
 .get(function(req, res) {
        mydataSchema.find(function(err, mydataSchema ) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(mydataSchema );
        });
    });
```